# XML parsing converting string to int

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I made a string that contains part of `xml` that I am working on. 
There are some integers in that file and I can not covert them from `String` to `int`. I try with `getAttributeValue(0)` but it didn`t work. So I was wondering if someone may have a solution for my problem. Thanks

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;



class ReadXMLFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("beginning: ", "Pocetak");

        //TODO - Call getFeeds Method to populate feeds list & return true/false depending on result of operation
        try {

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            String xmldata = <cenovnik>
<cenovnikStavkaList>
    <id>12195432</id>
    <izlaznaStanica>100</izlaznaStanica>
    <kategorijaVozila>0</kategorijaVozila>
    <ulaznaStanica>100</ulaznaStanica>
</cenovnikStavkaList>
<cenovnikStavkaList>
    <id>12197782</id>
    <izlaznaStanica>100</izlaznaStanica>
    <kategorijaVozila>1</kategorijaVozila>
    <ulaznaStanica>100</ulaznaStanica>
</cenovnikStavkaList>
```

```
             xpp.setInput(new StringReader( xmldata ));
            Log.d("step1a", "string");
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = xpp.getName();
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                    Log.d("Step 2a: ","Start document");
                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    Log.d("Step 2b: ", "Start tag " + xpp.getName());
                    if(xpp.getName().equals("cenovnikStavkaList")){

                        String testid = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "id");
                        Log.d("Step 2d - ID: ", testid);
                    }


                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

                     Log.d("Step 2d: ", xpp.getText());

                }

                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
            Log.d("Step 2e: ", "End document");
            Log.d("Step 2: ", "radi");

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result){
            Log.d("END TEST","done");
        }
    }

    public static InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
        try {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have attributes (with or without integer values) in there. You're looking to convert text values for elements from `String` to integer types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers are inside leaf tags, like `<id>12195432</id>`.

The XML parsing events needs states, keeping data in variables.
Officially you could have several TEXTs inside two tags, hence:

```
StringBuilder text;

            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                text = new StringBuilder();
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                if (text != null) {
                    text.append(xpp.getText());
                }
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (text != null) { 
                    String s = text.toString();
                    try {
                        int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
                        // do something with number n
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // No number
                    }
                    text = null;
                }
            }
```

Create a new field cenovnikStavkaList with itself a field id for every same named tag, and do

```
cenovnikStavkaList.id = n;
```

and on END_TAG add it to a list.